# Explain boost::filesystem's portable generic path format in C++

Tags: c++, path, portability, boost-filesystem

I am trying to understand [portable generic path format](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Pathname-formats) and everything is not clicking. Can someone please explain this in terms of examples? I also have been told that I can use the forward slash in windows because windows understands both. Also is it considered good/safe style to use forward slash in windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think an example is just `a/b/c`—the portable path format follows POSIX conventions. If you use `boost::basic_path`, you don't have to care about the correct slashes, the library knows how to convert the portable format to the native format. However, you should always use `boost::wpath` instead of `boost::path`, otherwise (I think) you cannot work with Unicode filenames on Windows.